# How do I get odd and even values in a Django for loop template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have this code

```
{% for o in some_list %}
```

Now I want to do some stuff if I am on an even line. How can I do that?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby

```
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}even{% else %}odd{% endif %}
```

Comment: +1. Also worth pointing out the `cycle` tag, depending on what/why exactly you want to do something only on even lines.

Comment: True. Thanks for adding that. There was a bug / unexpected behavior associated w/ the cycle tag; maybe that has since been fixed...

Comment: As of even date I don't think it has. Current cycle control appears to be vestigial at best - I don't see any way to reset a cycle, just a way to move it along.

Answer (score 98):

In first level cycle:

```
{% cycle 'odd' 'even' %}
```

### Reference:

- [Documentation for `cycle` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle)

Comment: Since there are multiple ways to use this tag, this answer could be improved with examples, like what's in Django's documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle

Answer (score 8):

```
<div class="row">
{% for post in posts %}
      {% cycle 'odd' 'even' %}
      {% if cycle == 'odd' %}
        <div class="col-md-6">Odd posts</div>
      {% else %}
        <div class="col-md-6">Even posts</div>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

**OR**

```
<div class="row">
{% for post in posts %}
   {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}
        <div class="col-md-6">Even posts</div>
      {% else %}
        <div class="col-md-6">Odd posts</div>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="row">
{% for post in posts %}
   {% if loop.index is divisibleby 2 %}
        <div class="col-md-6">Even posts</div>
      {% else %}
        <div class="col-md-6">Odd posts</div>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

http://mitsuhiko.pocoo.org/jinja2docs/html/templates.html#id3