# How can I check for loop count? (and whether it is even or odd)

Tags: django

```
{% for p in posts %}
   <div id="even">{{ p.title }}</div>
   <div id="odd">{{ p.title }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I need create something like this:

```
{% for p in posts %}
   {% if forloop_count is even %}
       <div id="even">{{ p.title }}</div>
   {% else %}
       <div id="odd">{{ p.title }}</div>
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

How can I check for loop count? (and whether it is even or odd)

Comment: Look better for the answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571966/how-to-get-odd-even-value-in-django-for-loop-in-template

Answer (score 3):

Is that your real underlying requirement, or are you simply trying to cycle between two div classes?  Do they have to be odd/even, or just alternating?

```
{% for o in some_list %}
    <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">
        ...
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/

In your case it would be:

```
{% for p in posts %}
    <div id="{% cycle 'even' 'odd' %}">{{ p.title }}</div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [divisableby](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby)

```
{% for p in posts %}
   {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"2" %} {# is even #}
       <div id="even">{{ p.title }}</div>
   {% else %}
       <div id="odd">{{ p.title }}</div>
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

or if its simply for a id use [cycle](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle) e.g.

```
{% cycle 'odd' 'even' %}
```