# I have list of N items. need to show every four item in different divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, django-templates

I need to implement a carousel/slider. which has to display max four items in a row and than next slides have 4 items and so on. I have a list of items from back end and want to show first 4 elements of it in 1st slide and than next 4 items in next slide and so on.
I have html template which is showing hard coded items but I want to show dynamic data here (Loop on item div for next slides and inside loop on col-md-3 div to show 4 items in a slide ).

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
   <div class="item  active">
       <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="item-slider">
                   <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="{% 
                       static 'images/t1.jpg' %}"></a>
                    <div class="item-cont">
                       <h3>Title</h3>
                        <p>Description</p>
                         <a href="#" class="btn orange-btn btn-block 
                         more-btn" data-toggle="modal" data- 
                         target="#tenants1">More Details</a>
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                   <div class="item-slider">
                      <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="{% 
                       static 'images/t1.jpg' %}"></a>
                      <div class="item-cont">
                         <h3>Title</h3>
                         <p>Description</p>
                         <a href="#" class="btn orange-btn btn-block 
                         more-btn" data-toggle="modal" data- 
                         target="#tenants1">More Details</a>
                     </div>
                </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   /// AGAIN LOOP ITERATION ON ITEM DIV FOR NEXT SLIDE.

<div class="item  active">
       <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="item-slider">
                   <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="{% 
                       static 'images/t1.jpg' %}"></a>
                    <div class="item-cont">
                       <h3>Title</h3>
                        <p>Description</p>
                         <a href="#" class="btn orange-btn btn-block 
                         more-btn" data-toggle="modal" data- 
                         target="#tenants1">More Details</a>
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                   <div class="item-slider">
                      <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src=" 
                      {% static 'images/t1.jpg' %}"></a>
                      <div class="item-cont">
                         <h3>Title</h3>
                         <p>Description</p>
                         <a href="#" class="btn orange-btn btn-block 
                         more-btn" data-toggle="modal" data- 
                         target="#tenants1">More Details</a>
                     </div>
                </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>


I need to apply 2 loops (1st for slider and 2nd to show four items in  slider)
```

Comment: You should add the code you've attempted to your question. Or are you asking us to write it all for you?

Comment: I have all data in property object and want to loop it like {% for item in property %} 
{% endfor %}. I have no idea how to loop in this scenario so need yours help to do it.

Comment: This should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571966/how-do-i-get-odd-and-even-values-in-a-django-for-loop-template